# Clojure STM ambiguity factor

Tags: clojure, stm

In Clojure we use STM for Concurrency.

My question is STM uses point in time value of data , isn't this introduce ambiguity ?

How could we know what value is accessed ?

Answer (score 8):

The STM in Clojure provides (through [`ref`](http://clojure.org/refs)s and [`dosync`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/dosync)) a transaction context where all updates are guaranteed to be made "at the same time" to all the refs involved when viewed from the outside world.

The objective is to maintain consistency of the values in the system, the typical example is the transfer of money between two bank accounts. If you are transferring, say, 100 dollars from account A to account B, then you'll want to have the amounts for A and B changed simultaneously.

In this example there's actually no ambiguity in the values read for the amounts that are being handled inside the transaction, because only the following situations are possible at the moment the read from outside the transaction is done:

1. The transaction has begun but is not yet finished, so the values have not been "officially" changed. The transaction can later be committed or retried, but when you read them, that was the state of each account.
2. The transaction has finished so the amounts read are the modified values.

When inside the transaction, the `ref`s you only read (and don't modify) *could* change their value from one point of the transaction to the other, this is called *write skew* (see [Clojure Programming](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1449394701) - Chapter 4, Refs, Write Skew). In order to avoid this you can use [`ensure`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/ensure) (instead of [`deref`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/deref)), this will cause that if the value for any of these `ref`s changes (the ones you only read), then the whole transaction will be retried.

Answer (score 4):

Clojurians use the words 'time' and 'value' with very specific meanings in this context to remove such ambiguity. In this context 'time' is 'time in a sequence' or epochal time rather than time as in time on the wall. So **time describes which value in the sequence of values for this identity**.

Value is the unchanging contents of an identity at a point in time. This value can be simple (a primitive or atomic value) or compound and made of arbitrarily structured unchanging values. The important part is that **values do not change so if you want to know which value was used you can simply print or log it**

I highly reccommend this video on [values, state and identity](http://www.infoq.com/presentations/Are-We-There-Yet-Rich-Hickey)